# Keeping a ROS thread running indefinitely on a Raspberry PI 3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm having a lot of problems working with raspberry pi and ROS kinetic.

The project is simple, I'm taking information from the Raspberry's GPIOs in order to communicate some process through iot_bridge. Due the kind of the project is mandatory that the program keep working for at least a day, the more time the better.

But I can only make it work for around half hour and then the loop stop without giving an error or a message, it only gets frozen.

I suspect, is a memory problem but I'm not sure. Does any one have an idea of what could it be and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263136/keeping-a-ros-thread-running-indefinitely-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/) by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2017-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-03**:
Maybe try to run your program in a debugger (such as GDB) and interrupt it when it gets stuck, to see where it's stuck?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-06-14**:
Please copy-paste the output. Posting it as a screenshot is the least helpful and [discouraged in the support guideline](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do).

**Comment by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) on 2017-06-14**:
I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, I have found the problem.

I was making the ros launch and all the other process through ssh, in order to control it remotely.

Therefore, it was needed to use a local network. If the connection is broken, the ssh will wait unit the connection is reestablished. Because if that it stops the process and put in a queue all the commands, which were not received by the ssh connection.

The answer is to implement an ethernet connection, or run  the nodes directly on the raspberry.

With this method is was able to run 2 days long.

---

Originally posted by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) with karma: 90 on 2017-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2